# How do I initialize an empty EnumSet in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, enums, enumset

I'm pretty new to Kotlin and trying to create a sort of bitset enum where ints correspond to state and I can toggle individual states by toggling individual bits. But I'm stuck on where an object can have no state.

https://pl.kotl.in/L_fTBahVN

```
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    var d = Door(100, EnumSet.noneOf(Status))
}

enum class Status(intValue: Int) {
    OPEN(1),
    CLOSED(1 shl 1),
    CRACKED(1 shl 2),
    BROKEN(1 shl 3)
}

class Door(val id: Int, val status: EnumSet<Status>) {}
```

This code fails with the error `Classifier 'Status' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here`

I was reading another question where they said to use `Status.class` inside the `EnumSet.noneOf`, but that throws even more errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
EnumSet.noneOf(Status::class.java)
```

`Status::class` is similar to `Status.class` in Java, but gets a Kotlin `kotlin.reflect.KClass` instead. To get the Java `java.lang.Class` that `EnumSet.noneOf` takes, you access the `java` property.